# psql telling me "database does not exist" in some places, recognizing it in others

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm trying to run these commands from this tutorial (http://jamiecook.wordpress.com/2011/11/24/setting-up-postgresql-postgis-for-rails-on-ubuntu/)

```
sudo su - postgres
createdb -E UTF8 template_postgis # Create the template spatial database.
createlang -d template_postgis plpgsql # Adding PLPGSQL language support.
psql -d osm -f /usr/share/postgresql/8.4/contrib/postgis-1.5/postgis.sql
psql -d osm -f /usr/share/postgresql/8.4/contrib/postgis-1.5/spatial_ref_sys.sql
cat <<EOS | psql -d template_postgis
UPDATE sample_postgis_db SET datistemplate = TRUE WHERE datname = 'template_postgis';
REVOKE ALL ON SCHEMA public FROM public;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO public;
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO postgres;
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE ON TABLE public.geometry_columns TO PUBLIC;
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE ON TABLE public.spatial_ref_sys TO PUBLIC;
GRANT ALL ON geometry_columns TO PUBLIC;
GRANT ALL ON geography_columns TO PUBLIC;
GRANT ALL ON spatial_ref_sys TO PUBLIC;
VACUUM FULL FREEZE;
EOS
```

and am getting the error:

```
ERROR:  relation "sample_postgis_db" does not exist
LINE 1: UPDATE sample_postgis_db SET datistemplate=TRUE WHERE datnam...
```

But it certainly does exist:

```
psql -d postgres
\list
#=>
...
sample_postgis_db | postgres     | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
...
```

I can login to it:

```
psql -d sample_postgis_db
```

but even when I run that UPDATE line (nonsensically of course, but its a good test I think) inside of the db's psql, it **still** doesn't recognize **itself**.

```
sample_postgis_db=# UPDATE sample_postgis_db SET datistemplate=TRUE WHERE datname = "template_postgis";
ERROR:  relation "sample_postgis_db" does not exist
LINE 1: UPDATE sample_postgis_db SET datistemplate=TRUE WHERE datnam...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial has:

```
UPDATE pg_database SET datistemplate = TRUE WHERE datname = 'template_postgis';
```

that you replaced by this:

```
UPDATE sample_postgis_db SET datistemplate = TRUE WHERE datname = 'template_postgis';
```

This replacement is uncalled for, since what is updated here is a system table, not a database name.

Answer (score 0):

I hate how mysterious this is...and maybe its just because I altered `sample_postgis_db`'s role to `SUPERUSER` (out of desperation), but it just started working...